# Simple substitutions using symbolic computing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

Suppose I have the following MATLAB code.

```
syms a b c1 c2

c1 = a + b + pi*b
c2 = a + b + 0.5*b
```

Then c<sub>1</sub> gets evaluated to `a + b + pi*b` and c<sub>2</sub> to `a + (3*b)/2`

However, I need MATLAB to calculate double-precision values for the coefficients for `a` and `b` and not just symbolic expressions.

How do I do this? e.g. I want c<sub>1</sub> to be evaluated as `a + 4.1416*b` and c<sub>2</sub> as `a + 1.5*b`.

Also, suppose I am interested in doing arithmetic like c<sub>1</sub>*c<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>*5, I would like the 
coefficients of `a` and `b` to evaluated as numbers.

How should I do this?

Comment: @ChristianClason - feel free to move your comments to an answer.

Comment: @AronAhmadia - done!

Answer (score 4):

To evaluate a symbolic expression numerically, you can use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to insert numerical values for symbolic variables:

```
>> subs(c1,{a,b},{1.1,1.2})

ans =

    6.0699
```

(Note that as long as `a` and/or `b` are symbolic variables, I don't see a  point in evaluating `pi` or `3/2` numerically. However, [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) seems to do what you want.)